Fresh install samba active directory - provisioning tool takes forever?
I have a pretty strong server (AMD ryzen 9, 32GB ram) and I am trying to install samba server as active directory domain controller. Following the official docs from samba, I run into a strange issue.
When I run:
samba-tool domain provision --use-rfc2307 --interactive

the tool seems to hang up at repacking database
INFO 2024-04-06 11:33:51,295 pid:31761 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1523: Setting up sam.ldb data
INFO 2024-04-06 11:33:51,322 pid:31761 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1553: Setting up well known security principals
INFO 2024-04-06 11:33:51,333 pid:31761 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1567: Setting up sam.ldb users and groups
INFO 2024-04-06 11:33:51,394 pid:31761 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py #1575: Setting up self join
check_spn_alias_collision: trying to add SPN 'DNS/dc1.sb.local' on 'CN=dns-dc1,CN=Users,DC=sb,DC=local' when 'host/dc1.sb.local' is on 'CN=DC1,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=sb,DC=local'
Repacking database from v1 to v2 format (first record CN=dhcp-Identification,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=sb,DC=local)
Repack: re-packed 10000 records so far
Repacking database from v1 to v2 format (first record CN=mSMQQueue-Display,CN=C0A,CN=DisplaySpecifiers,CN=Configuration,DC=sb,DC=local)
Repacking database from v1 to v2 format (first record CN=3c784009-1f57-4e2a-9b04-6915c9e71961,CN=Operations,CN=DomainUpdates,CN=System,DC=sb,DC=local)

I see more information on this behavior here but there is no further information available on how the issue was resolved.
Anybody that recognizes this problem and knows how to fix / workaround?

I reinstalled Ubuntu server which solved the problem.
I hope there comes a better solution for the next guy.
